# visual studio and sql how to select multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio

First I made a login screen on visual basic with sql, but I need to get those passwords and usernames form two tables. So I have done as

```
Query = "select * from jofy.user jofy.artist where username='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"`
```

I need to get those information from both user and artist, but it always shows an error

```
i've tried using jofy.user, jofy.artist

jofy.user and jofy.artist
jofy.user or jofy.artist
```

if anyone knows how to fix this, I would appreciate help with it.

Comment: First try to decide if this question is for Sql Server or MySql (two different database you know right?)

Comment: what you error get?. and what is the meaning of 'i've tried using jofy.user...'

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL `JOIN`

SQL `JOIN` is a method to retrieve data from two or more database tables.

example T-SQL:

```
select 
        user.* 
        ,artist.*
  from jofy.user as user
     join jofy.artist as artist 
         on artist.userID = user.id
where
     user.username = 'user.name'
     and user.password = 'pass'
...
```